# How to iterate through the string completely in python?

Tags: python, string, loops

I am learning python and I would like the turtle to move according to the string that I have input. If I only have one character in my string, the turtle will move. However, if I have more than two characters in my string, my turtle will not move at all. Here is my code:

```
 import turtle

 wn = turtle.Screen()

 crystal = turtle.Turtle()
 crystal.speed(0)

 def instructions(string):
     for char in string:
         if char in string == "F":
             crystal.forward(100)

         elif char in string == "+":
             crystal.right(60)

         elif char in string == "X":
             print ("X is an invalid command")

 instructions("F+F")

 wn.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to say `char in string` twice.  After the `for`, just use `char`.

Like:

```
for char in string:
    if char == "F":
        crystal.forward(100)
```

Comment: Also, in the future naming variables 'string' and 'char' may end up being problematic, as keywords are sometimes the same names.

Comment: neither "char" nor "string" is a builtin type or keyword.